# Jquery OFF and ON

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable and off click on the div based on the value from text box when value is 1 and enable to click other than 1. off is working correctly and On is not working. When I change the value I am not able to click again.

HTML code

```
<div id="searchs" style="display:inline-block; cursor: pointer;"><img alt="search" width="16" height="16" src="images/search_lg.png" /></div>

<input  name="spcode" type="number" id="spcode" size="25"  min="0" max="9" onkeyup="enableSearchImageSave();"/>
```

javascript code

```
function enableSearchImageSave(){
  if($('#spcode').val() == 1) {
    $("#searchs").off('click');
  } else {
    $("#searchs").on('click');//problem code
    $('#searchs').load(document.URL +  ' #searchs');
  } 
}
```

Comment: You need to add more specific information to this question. It is not really clear what you are asking. You mention a div but don't have one in your sample code? Are you trying to toggle an onclick function on the div?

Comment: The issue with your code is that you're calling `on('click')`, but not supplying a handler function. The original handler that you previously removed with `off()` is not magically re-attached.

Comment: i have added searchs div to above question i want to make that div click on and off based on the spcode

Answer (score 0):

On function requires an event handler:

```
$('#spcode').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('click turned on');
});
```

you can check this page about [.on and .off functions usage](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/).

Comment: spcode is text filed div id for img is searchs for which im trying to make off and on click based on spcode value